# Is reflecting on the stack trace dangerous in a release build?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

In C# consider the following statement:

```
string operation = new StackTrace(false).GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name;
```

Is this a dangerous construction in a release build, where the frames may be compiled to native code?

Comment: Dangerous as in "crashes everything"? Or "super-slow"? Or "reveals some secret information"? Or "returns different name than in debug build, so that my code that depends on it won't work"?

Comment: [GetCurrentMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod.aspx)?

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not dangerous per say, but you might not get all the information that you want from a release build that was built without debug symbols. Here's some information from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx):

> > StackTrace information will be most informative with Debug build configurations. By default, Debug builds include debug symbols, while Release builds do not. The debug symbols contain most of the file, method name, line number, and column information used in constructing StackFrame and StackTrace objects.

Comment: You can supply pdb files even with release build.

Comment: @Aliostad, Yep, that's why I wrote `release build that was built without debug symbols`, maybe it was a bit unclear. :)

Answer (score 3):

The CLR gives very strong guarantees about stack walks.  Necessarily so, they are very important to make the garbage collector and code access security work.  What you however cannot count on is that GetFrame(0) gives you the stack frame of your method.  Inlining code is an important jitter optimization.  At least not without explicitly suppressing the optimization with [MethodImpl], specifying MethodImplOptions.NoInlining on your method.

Both the stack walk and the optimization suppression are expensive so be sure this code isn't on your critical path.

Compiler support for this feature will be added to the next version of C#, version 5, with the [[CallerMemberName] attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK no.

Everything compiles to IL anyway. Methods will be known, you just need a pdb file - even if you do a release build.

You can set this in Advanced options on project properties

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the replies.

My problem was that I have experienced sporadic crashes with code including the listed statement (an access violation), however without the statement the code has been stable. But due to the replies it seems that I must look elsewere.